# Selecting column in dataframe returns NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to access a column in my dataframe using dataframe$column format. But it returns NULL. What am I doing wrong ? Please help[image: []

Comment: You didn't read in the individual columns, separated by commas. It only read in one big column and called it `V1`. Redo the read command. You want `df <- read.csv(..., sep=',')`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the output, you don't have a column called `Ozone`; the column, and the only one, you have is called `V1`. You will have to split the data in `V1` into columns. This can be done using `tidyr`'s `separate`, like so:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("Ozone,Solar.R,Wind,Temp,Month,Day",
         "41,190,7.4,67,5,1")
)
```

First, get your column names:

```
col_names <- unlist(strsplit(df$V1[1], ","))
```

The column names are now stored in a vector:

```
col_names
[1] "Ozone"   "Solar.R" "Wind"    "Temp"    "Month"   "Day"
```

Now transform `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
# first rename the col to be transformed:
  rename("Ozone,Solar.R,Wind,Temp,Month,Day" = V1) %>% 
# remove the first row, which is now redundant:
  slice(2:nrow(.)) %>% 
# separate into columns using the `col_names`:
  separate(1, into = col_names, sep = ",")
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
```